# How to avoid repeated polymer imports when using multiple polymer elements?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am new to polymer 2, and it seems, to load polymer element, you import a html file that has these 3 html imports:

```
1. the polyfill
2. the main polymer element class
3. and then potentially extras like iron-input.html or dom-repeat.html
```

If I then import 5 polymer element html files for 5 different elements, into my main page, I will have 5 times the above 3 imports. How do you avoid all that duplication, and massive import into the DOM?

Am I supposed to remove all the import statements from the 5 files manually? And just keep 1 of each?

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/quick-tour

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of that is necessary, because HTML Imports are de-duplicated by design.

This means that any occurrence of `<link rel="import" href="polymer.html">` will only ever be downloaded once by the browser.

As a side fact, most imported HTML will not contain HTML directly but rather scripts and [HTML templates](https://www.webcomponents.org/community/articles/introduction-to-template-element). These templates are then used to create actual HTML content to be inserted into the page. Most notably, these templates define the appearance of custom elements.

---

You will see how these pieces all fall into place to create the Web Components specification:

- **Custom elements** define building blocks of web components
- The behavior and appearance of custom elements is defined (roughly speaking), but **HTML templates** and scripts
- These scripts are distributed as self-contained HTML files consumed with **HTML imports**

Comment: Even if it is downloaded once, the problem is that the code is inserted into the DOM for each <link> tag right?

Comment: How **inserted into the DOM**?

Comment: I was doing  some testing actually, and what I find is that, when you import a html file, all it can do is evaluate any html imports it does and run scripts, but it does not add any regular html to the dom. Is that right?

Comment: So if a html file you import has <div>hello</div>, you don't see that `hello` on your page.

Comment: No, it does not. Much like adding a `<script src="code.js">` doesn't insert the contents of `code.js` directly into the page

Comment: So then if that's the case, why even have html imports, why not just use regular script tags to load scripts? Then script tags can load more scripts using es6 import/export?

Comment: This is a good question. First reason, ES6 import/export has been struggling to go live in browsers. You need tools like Webpack. Web Components spec strives for browser compatibility and polyfills were necessary.

Comment: Secondly, if two independent components referenced some other like `iron-input`, you would load and run `iron-input.js` twice. You can guard against that but it's a burden on devs. HTML imports liberate you from that.

Comment: ok so there are some differences between script tags and html tags. Also i think another difference is any html stuff in an html import is only temporary and only encapsulated in the html import. Which allows use of template elements for polymer.